# How to parse the html which is embedded in a string inside a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aditapillai/am56g5g9/)

```
<script>
  angular.module('module', []);

  angular.module('module').controller('hello', function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      "text": "<u>HelloWorld</u>"
    };

  });

</script>

<body>

  <div ng-app='module' ng-controller='hello'>
    Current:{{obj.text}}

    <br>
    <br> Expected:<u>HelloWorld</u>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to read an object stored in a **JSON** and then print it on my web page.

I have provided a link to the code above.

I am expecting the output to be a string "HelloWorld" which is underline.

ps:

- I cannot edit the **JSON**
- obj is the object that is being fetched, I could not share the **JSON** so i have used a hardcoded value.

Comment: There isn't any JSON shown in your code. You have an object.

Comment: Correct, I used a dummy object, but that object is being fetched from a JSON,since  i couldn't share the entire JSON file here, i hardcoded the object in the script.
Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` for that kind of purpose. you have to include `ngSanitize` from `angular-sanitize`.

```
<p ng-bind-html="obj.text"></p>
```

The example is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sbtgbkgu/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to just use a regular expression like so:

```
$scope.obj.text =  $scope.obj.text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/am56g5g9/7/)

Comment: I want the <u> tag to get applied to the String rather than removing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`angular-sanitize` module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize):

```
<script src="path/to/installed/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module("module", ["ngSanitize"]);

    angular.module('module').controller('hello', function($scope) {
        $scope.obj = {
            "text": "<u>HelloWorld</u>"
        };

    });

</script>
```

And your html:

```
<div ng-app='module' ng-controller='hello'>
    Current: <p ng-bind-html="obj.text"></p>

    <br>
    <br> Expected:<u>HelloWorld</u>
</div>
```